# Optimizing the merge_intervals problems (used bfs)

Tags: python, breadth-first-search

I am working on a problem to merge overlapping intervals:
Problem Link: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/merging-intervals/

I tried to implement bfs for this problem because.....why not?

The solution that I found out works just fine. The problem arises when the data set is very large. It becomes relatively slow compared to other methods to solve this problem. I want to optimize this code as much as I can so it isn't that slow.

I have tried dictionary for lookup, set for the lookup to check if the node is visited or not. Still, the solution does not show considerable improvements. Please suggest me how can I make it fast. I think it is currently running in O(nlogn)+O(n)

```
def merge_graph(intervals,visited,i):
    #print ("-----")
    q=deque()
    q.append((intervals[i][0],intervals[i][1]))
    visited.add(i)
    temp_result=[]
    #temp_result.append(intervals[i][0])
    start_lim=sys.maxsize
    end_lim=-sys.maxsize
    while q:
        #print (q)
        left,right=q.popleft()
        start_lim=min(start_lim,left)
        end_lim=max(end_lim,right)
        for j in range(len(intervals)):
            if j not in visited and right>=intervals[j][0] and left<=intervals[j][1]:
                visited.add(j)
                q.append((intervals[j][0],intervals[j][1]))
    temp_result.append(start_lim)
    temp_result.append(end_lim)
    return (temp_result)
n=len(intervals)
visited=[0]*(n+1)
#uncomment this line for result is sorted order
#intervals.sort()
merged_intervals=[]
visited=set()
for i in range(n):
    if i not in visited:
        merged_intervals.append(merge_graph(intervals,visited,i))
return (merged_intervals)
```

Comment: The runtime of your algorithm is not O(n log n). The BFS will visit every interval, and then for every interval, you traverse the entire interval list again. So this part of your algorithm gives you O(n^2), which dominates your runtime.